# Diablo 2 Ubuntu 18 Bionic

Tags: 18.04, wine, playonlinux

It isn't my first time playing Diablo2 on Linux, I had the experience in Ubuntu 16 and Linux Mint. However, in Ubuntu 18 Bionic server when I start Diablo I get the image like transparent white and when I start opening Battle.net It crashes. I have installed q4wine, wine-stable, everything I tried fails and I have the same result.